# onChangeText not working when passing the onChangeText parameter outside the component

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is my first time making a test but I'm having trouble where onChangeText doesn't change the value of the TextInput component

```
const Example = ({onChangeText, value}) => {
return (<TextInput testID={'input'} onChangeText={onChangeText} value={value} />)
}

test('onChangeText', () => {
        const onChangeText = jest.fn()
        const value = 'test input'

        const { getByTestId } = render(
            <Example onChangeText={onChangeText} value={value} />
        );

        const input = getByTestId('input')
        fireEvent.changeText(input, 'uno');
        expect(input.props.value).toBe('uno');
    });
```

the value of the test obtained remains 'test input' does not change to 'uno'

how do we make the onChangeText in test in change the value of the TextInput value if we provide the onChangeText props?

Comment: You have to create a new state. `onChamngeText` have to change that state to a new value. Use this state as `value` prop

Answer (score 0):

component receives input value es props and I assume there is some input which is using the value.

So, it means, that your component is *uncontrolled*. And in this case, it is okay, that your test does not pass. It is not the library issue, but the code.

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/978

[https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:~:text=In%20a%20controlled%20component%2C%20form,form%20values%20from%20the%20DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20controlled%20component%2C%20form,form%20values%20from%20the%20DOM).

You can read about controlled and uncontrolled components more here.